# How to create a Spring Data JPA query that will return objects matching 3 parameters from a list of objects of the same type

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I would like to create a query created from method name - examples :

```
List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(String emailAddress, String lastname);
List<User> findByAgeIn(Collection<Age> ages)
```

that would basically combine the two above methods. I have an entity with like 15 parameters, but only 3 are pertinent here, lets call them x y z. I would like to create a query that would basically work like

```
List<MyClass> FindByXAndYAndZIn(List<Myclass> list)
```

And return all objects from repo that have the same x y z as any element of the list

1. Is it even possible using only queries created form method names
2. If it is, how should it be done?

!!EDIT!!: Just realised the post i wrote is misleading - i can't use

```
List<MyClass> FindByXAndYAndZIn(String X String Y String Z List<Myclass> list)
```

Because the specific values of X Y and Z are in elements of the list. I would need something like

```
List<MyClass> FindByXAndYAndZIn(List<Myclass> list)
```

That would get the x y z for the first element of the list and get the objects from repository that have the same x y z. then do the same for next element of list and the next etc. and return all matching objects.

Comment: Im surprised List<User> findByEmailAddressAndLastnameAndAgeIn(String emailAddress, String lastname, Collection<Age> ages) doesnt work. You need to use lowercase find

Comment: Yes it does, but sadly i was slightly misleading in the first iteration of my question, hope you see the updated version

Comment: So X, Y and Z are values of same field, and String/Varchar? So List<MyClass> findByColumnMappingIn(List<String> list)

Comment: nope, X Y Z are 3 different fields in an entity

Comment: Cant be done using spring data JPA unless you use a native or custom query

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want a query like -

```
SELECT * FROM myclass_table WHERE X in (X, Y, Z);
```

This should be possible in spring data jpa -

```
List<MyClass> FindByXIn(List<String> X);
```

The assumption is that X is a String, although the query can be changed for a more complex JPA object